# Live Notifications UML Class Diagram

Tags: php, symfony, notifications, uml, entity-relationship

I am trying to implement a live notification system (like fb, xing, twitter..). Therefore, I created an UML class diagram before building the entities. The showcase is the following:

---

> EDIT: I Thought about this approach and it seems as if this is not the right one. Let's check the following scenarion: User U adds at Event E's image I a comment C. How to store this correctly, I mean EventNotification only has a reference on the Event E, but not on I and C. Therefore I would need to create an "EventImageNotification" class as well and this would be a mess. Would it be a nicer solution to just have one "Notification" class and add a "metadata" field to it, which stores references to all involved fields?

---

(I am using an OR-Mapper to implement relations later).

[ 1 ] One user can create events, e.g. "Silvester Party 2015". (OneToMany).
This event has a dashboard, where Users can subscribe to receive updates when the creator posts something on that event (ManyToMany).

[ 2 ] When a user posts something on the dashboard of the event, subscribed users should receive a Notification. Therefore, I created the EventNotification class. Relation between user and EventNotification is ManyToMany.

[ 3 ] To keep it clean, I created an AbstractNotification class which is related to a Notification type. A notification type is something like name = "EventPost" and template = "User **user** has posted something new on event __event".

[ 4 ] The abstract class NotificationConnector gives fields to the mapping class between EventNotification and User (UserEventNotification). I created them to extend it easily in the future, e.g. a User can create Books that also trigger events etc. Then I would need to create one "BookNotification" and one "UserBookNotification" class to store notifications for this new entity.

Is this approach a good one or fully messed up? Please tell me your ideas about this diagram:

(The arrows to build associations should have been normal lines, the tool I used just couldn't do that).

[image: Notification UML]

Comment: Update: I am now using a metadata field in combination with a NotificationType and it's working for all kind of nested notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few observations:

- The two abstract classes seem to be superfluous since you use them only in one context.
- The `has`connection from `User` should go to `UserEndNotification` rather than the abstract class (which I recommend to drop anyway).
- I'd make `NotificationType` an `<<enumeration>>`
- rather than using an `owns` relation I would use an association class between `User` and `Event` and add an `isOwner` and `isSubscriber` property.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your thoughts. I will comment your points. [1] I created the abstract classes because in future, there will come more entities that will get connected to the abstracted classes. [2] This sounds more logical! [3] Also read this, but then it would be harder to administrate the names & themplates through an admin area ? [4] this sounds pretty nice, I also thought of that but didn't know what the recommended / more performant way would be. Normally, you can have multiple separate relations between two classes, but I think both approaches should work.

Comment: 3) Depends. There are pro and cons. Just a thought. 4) Does not tell about performance. This is left to implementation. Your m-n relation is already an association class (though a simple one) you likely would map via a table with two foreign keys.